# Cannot Obtain text from 'Selected' Class Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectric

I am trying to get the text of an option value in a `<select\>` component. I am using the jQuery plugin 'selectric'.

The following returns an empty string instead of `Grid`.

```js
const option = $('.selected').text()
console.log(option)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/selectric@1.13.0/public/jquery.selectric.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/selectric@1.13.0/public/selectric.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="selectric-scroll">
  <ul>
    <li data-index="0" class="highlighted">List</li>
    <li data-index="1" class="last selected">Grid</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Why does this return an empty string and not `Grid`? Is there a way to get the text `Grid`?

I attempted to use `text()` to obtain text but got empty string.

Comment: Firstly, please insert code in to the question as text so that it can easily be copied and amended - not as an image. Secondly, I've created an executable snippet from the code, where it seems to work fine. I assume there's some implementation code missing from your use of Selectric, as your code is using a `ul`, not a `select`...?

Comment: As far as I can tell from `https://selectric.js.org/` - [tag:jquery-selectric] is a plugin to convert a `select` to an improved UI.  1) you don't have a `select` and 2) you don't call `$("select").selectric()`  to initialise it.

Comment: "*I am trying to get the text of an option value in a `<select>` component*" - please include that `<select>` in your question - at the moment you *only* have a `ul`, no `select`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: I tried a minimal reproducible example in JSFiddle and the error doesn't occur - I think selectric somehow makes it impossible for you to select the value of an option. I posted the code as an image because Stack Overflow wasn't letting me post it which normally doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the function returning an empty string was that the component hadn't properly loaded in the DOM first before the function was running, so I just added an Add Event Listener:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
const option = $('.selected').text()
console.log(option)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have your JavaScript code in another external file, then your code would work fine only by adding the defer or async attribute to the script element where you referenced the external script.

Or you can just place the script at the bottom of the body element.